# enable a disabled select when choose a value in another select tag

Tags: javascript, html, disabled-input

I have these two select tag:

```
<select>
  <option value="car">car</option>
  <option value="truck">truck</option>
  <option value="moto">moto</option>
  <option value="none">none</option>
</select>

<select disabled>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

As you can see, my second select have the disabled attribute. I would like in javascript, when I selected the option **"car"** in my first select, the second select with the car's choice become enabled to make a choice.

How can I proceed in javascript?

Comment: then, why do you tag the question with jquery?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**JavaScript Version:**

```js
document.getElementById("one").onchange = function () {
  document.getElementById("two").setAttribute("disabled", "disabled");
  if (this.value == 'car')
    document.getElementById("two").removeAttribute("disabled");
};
```

```html
<select id="one">
  <option value="car">car</option>
  <option value="truck">truck</option>
  <option value="moto">moto</option>
  <option value="none">none</option>
</select>

<select disabled id="two">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

**jQuery Version:**

```js
$('#one').change(function() {
  $('#two').prop('disabled', true);
  if ($(this).val() == 'car') {
    $('#two').prop('disabled', false);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="one">
  <option value="car">car</option>
  <option value="truck">truck</option>
  <option value="moto">moto</option>
  <option value="none">none</option>
</select>

<select id="two" disabled>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 3):

1. Put `ids` on your `selects` to easily target them
2. In the handler, by default, `disable` the second `select` element
3. If the current `val` of the first select is *car*, then set `disabled` to **false**

```js
$('#AutoType').change(function() {
  $('#Model').prop('disabled', true);
  if ($(this).val() == 'car') {
    $('#Model').prop('disabled', false);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="AutoType">
  <option value="car">car</option>
  <option value="truck">truck</option>
  <option value="moto">moto</option>
  <option value="none">none</option>
</select>

<select id="Model" disabled>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
<form id="creation" name="creation" onchange="handleSelect()">
    <select name="select01" id="select01">>
      <option value="car">car</option>
      <option value="truck">truck</option>
      <option value="moto">moto</option>
      <option value="none">none</option>
    </select>

    <select name="select02" id="select02" disabled>
      <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
      <option value="saab">Saab</option>
      <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
      <option value="audi">Audi</option>
    </select>
    </form>

    function handleSelect() {
     if (this.value == '01') {
         document.getElementById('select02').disabled = true;
     } else {
         document.getElementById('select02').disabled = false;
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to assign an `id` to you select element like:

```
<select id="my-input-id" disabled>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>

 document.getElementById('my-input-id').disabled = false;
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to simply use a frontend framework such as Angular or React.js or Ember?? It's much easier if you want to do something complicated.

A demo is as follows: 
http://jsfiddle.net/PxdSP/2244/

All you need to do is include angular.js in your website

```
<script src= "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js">
```

You can then assign logic to the controller and decide what you want to do with the select or divs.